# Invariant nature of mass and particle annihilation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, mass-energy, invariants, pair-production

Since mass is a Lorentz invariant, it can never change to preserve the vectorial nature of the four-momentum and the other four vectors. Thus the only interpretation of the energy-mass equation that I can give is that in
$$E^2=m^2+p^2$$
the first term, $m^2$ is a constant energy, that can never change, but can affect and can be affected by gravity, whereas the second term of $p^2$ can change. But if we write this expression as
$$E=\gamma m$$
Then some say that mass changes, in the sense that energy and mass are interchangeable, but what changes, is of course the $\gamma$ and not $m$.

In accordance with all this, how do particle annihilation and creation fit in the picture? Since annihilation means a change in mass, how is mass invariant?

I have no knowledge of quantum theory but from a lecture that I watched on special relativity, the professor said that the conflict solved by QFT was that in QM the probability of the particle existing should always be 1, whereas in SR particles can be annihilated. So it seems to me that the particle annihilation and invariant nature of the mass can be understood directly from SR and hence the question.

Comment: You seem to be confusing conserved quantities with Lorentz invariant quantities.

Answer (score 2):

> Since annihilation means a change in mass, how is mass invariant?

In this context, mass being invariant means it is Lorentz invariant, which means it is a concept that has the same numerical value in all inertial frames of reference. It *does not mean* it cannot change in time. If a small part of a rocket (judging by mass) leaves the rocket, and by rocket we mean the mass that moves together with the tip of the rocket, then mass of the rocket decreased, while remaining Lorentz invariant at all times.

Annihilation does not necessarily mean change in mass. When the pair electron-positron disappears, EM radiation is created. Mass of this radiation, defined by

$$
m_{rad}^2 = E_{rad}^2 - p_{rad}^2,
$$
is the same as mass of the system just before the transformation. This however is somewhat less than $2m_e$, due to negative energy of interaction in the system.

Comment: So just as Newtonian force is a Galilean invariant but still can change in time, so can mass. This makes sense however, I do not understand how mass is converted to energy in SR. From a mathematical point of view, $m$ is just a number thus your equation of radiation and mine are equivalent, but from a physical POV, I do not understand how mass can be converted into energy.

Comment: Mass cannot be converted to energy. Radioactive decay or annihilation transforms the form of energy, from concentrated energy in the bound state to dilute energy of the products. When the products of reaction spread away, tracking them is hard and mass of the system is not as interesting as part of the released energy, but mass defined as above is conserved just as energy is.

Comment: So my interpretation of mass is correct? "*...$m^2$
 is a constant energy, that can never change, but can affect and can be affected by gravity, whereas the second term of p2
 can change.*"

Comment: Mass of a thing can change when part of it goes away. Mass of an isolated system that does not lose or acquire parts cannot change.

Comment: I don't think gravity can change mass of a body.

Comment: We can have pair production in isolated system, where sure the effective mass doesn't change but the physical meaning of mass does change, how to take that into account?

Comment: "Physical meaning of mass does change" how?

Comment: In the sense that for a photon it's "effective" while for any massive particle, it's "real", thus restricting it from traveling at light speed.

Comment: "Photon" or an EM wave packet in the standard linear EM theory does not have "effective mass". It's mass is zero in the standard theory. It is possible it is non-zero and very small in reality, but no mass was ever detected. In standard theory, only two or more photons or EM wave packets, moving in different directions, have non-zero mass. I would not put too much importance on the idea "non-zero mass restricts body from traveling at light speed". Light speed is the speed limit for every form of energy, matter and radiation, and these things can approach it arbitrarily close.